# How to take multiples inputs in a single line in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get multiple inputs in a single line in python. This are the kind of inputs I am trying to take, the first line consists of the number of lines of input I will take:

```
3
1 2 3 
4 3
8 9 6 3
```

Is there any way to take that kind of input, without knowing how many inputs are going to be given per line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use.

```
separator = ' '
parameters = input("parameters:").split(separator)
```

e.g.

```
Python 3.6.5 (default, Mar 30 2018, 06:42:10)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> separator = '-'
>>> parameters = input("parameters:").split(separator)
parameters:5-6
>>> parameters
['5', '6']
>>>
```

Comment: It's tagged python3.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the map function that will append the inputs to a list
if , suppose you have to take any n no of inputs

```
arr = list(map(int,input().split()))
```

all the elements entered will be stored as integer in arr list.

Comment: `map` has nothing to do with `list`. It will just map all the elements to another element using a function.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to get two or more integer values from the user :

Method 1 : ***Using map() and split() function***

```
// Taking Common Variable v to get multiple user input

v = input("Enter the three numbers separated by a whitespace : ")

// Using map() and split() function to assign values to three variables a,b and c

a,b,c = map(int(),v.split())
```

Explanation :

1. When User inputs three values i.e. 10 20 30 which are separated by whitespace as per our direction, the variable **v** stores the valuesin form of String.
2. **v.split()** function is used to split the string substrings based on whitespace characters. i.e. ['10','20','30'].
3. **map()** function is used to convert each string values of the list into list of integer values and returns an iterator.
4. The iterator returned by map() is unpacked into three variables, a,b and c i.e. **a,b,c = 10,20,30**

In this way we can provide three integer user input values to three different variables. For Floating values, just replace ***int()*** function with ***float()***

Method 2 : ***Using list() , map() and split() methods***:

```
// Taking a variable to store the list of values

L = list(map(int(),input("Enter three values separated by space).split()))
```

Explanation :

1. **input()** function will take 3 values which will be stored as string in variable **L** i.e. 10 20 30
2. **split()** function works as mentioned above and stores the values in form of list of values i.e. ['10','20','30']
3. **map()** function works as described above and returns an iterator
4. **list()** function converts the iterator into list of values i.e. [10,20,30]

In this way we can provide List of integers user input values to a list variable. For Floating values, just replace ***int()*** function with ***float()***

Method 3 : ***Using List Comprehension Method()*** :

```
// Unpacking the variables using list comprehension

x,y,z = [int(x) for x in input("Enter two values : ").split()]
```

In this way we can provide three integer user input values to three different variables. For Floating values, just replace ***int()*** function with ***float()***